# Java Maven Project - Build Once and Deploy Multiple Environment

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, deployment, build

I am working on a maven project where **property file values needs to be changed based on environment but *same WAR file* should be deployed for all environment**. Here We have three option to achieve -

**1. Java Parameter Argument** - I know this is best option but we can't use this. We don't want to do any code level changes. We have multiple reasons behind this.

**2. WAR File Extract** -  This is one of way the to achieve. We can build the WAR once and during deployment , run the script to Unpack the War > Replace the property file value (env specific) > And then Pack the War. However we are not allowed to Unpacking. So this solution is not useful.

**3. Maven Profiling** - This is last approach which I see as solution. In Pom , I have defined multiple profiles. So based on profile we are copying property file on class path. **But here problem is** - We need to build the WAR per Environment which is breaking the requirement - " *Build Once and Deploy Everywhere*"

I need your suggestion and approach to meet my requirement - *Build Once Deploy for Multiple Environment*

I have few ideas which I am thinking to try but not sure whether this technically possible or not-

> Compile the source code once and Same compiled code can be used to
>   bundle the WAR. And During War bundling we can use the feature of
>   Maven Profiling to replace the Property file Value. But I don't know
>   How I can achieve using Maven , Pom.xml configuration.

I have attached my current maven profiling configuration snippet.

```
<profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <build>
                <pluginManagement>
                    <plugins>


                        <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.6</version>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <id>copy-prod-resources</id>
                                    <!-- <phase>process-classes</phase> -->
                                    <phase>validate</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
                                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                                        <resources>
                                            <resource>
                                                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/profiles/DEV</directory>
                                                <includes>
                                                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                                                </includes>
                                            </resource>
                                        </resources>
                                    </configuration>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>

                    </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

Comment: To really achieve this you need to remove the configuration (properties) from your war file ...and put the configuration outside....

Comment: But current project searches for those property file on class path. I need to make sure that property file should be available on class path.

Comment: Make separate jar files with the appropriate configuration for each environment...which can be deployed separately. Or you build via this: https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin (this prevents profiles etc.)

Comment: Thanks Khmarbaise , The maven plugin you have provided is exact solution of requirement however We can't use this plugin within the project until this is available as part of Maven Repository. The second option you have mentioned about Jar file. Do you have any sample project in GIT or any reference , which i can explore and implement. This will be very help full for me.

Comment: Can you explain this: `..can't use this plugin within the project until this is available as part of Maven Repository.`?

Comment: I am sorry , without searching in maven repository , I commented. I found this - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.soebes.smpp/smpp-plugins/5.0.0 . I will make changes in maven and will get back to you , in case of any issue related to pom configuration. Many Thanks.

Comment: The search for Central repository is: https://search.maven.org ...

Comment: The search for Central repository is: https://search.maven.org ...

Comment: Thanks for your input Khmarbaise. However I have preferred other way and that is working fine for me. What i did ...I have used ENVIRONMENT as JVM argument. So my application picks Env dynamically and points to Env Specific Property file path.                                                                                      
 String env = System.getProperty(ENV_PROPERTY_NAME);